# .htaccess case-insensitive directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case-insensitive

I access to the `file.php` writing `mydomain.com/file`. I need to be able to access also writing `mydomain.com/FILE`.

In .htaccess I use the following rules to remove extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

If this rules should be changed- it's up to you.

Comment: It's in private network. I need to minimize user mistakes.

Comment: Keep your files in lowercase and using `RewriteMap` convert each URL to lowercase. (requires access to Apache server config)

Comment: The files are in lowercase. Which changes should I make in config, and how should I use RewriteMap? Could you write in Answer form, so I could mark it if it's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define this `RewriteMap` in Apache or `vhost` config:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then inside your .htaccess have an additional rule to lowercase all uppercase URIs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# convert each REQUEST_URI to lowercase
RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z]+.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L,NE]

# internally add .php 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Should I write 'RewriteMap lc int:tolower' in .htaccess or? I'll check it tomorrow and write. Thanks!

Comment: No, `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` must be placed in `httpd.con` or your vhost config. `RewriteMap` isn't allowed from .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

Use `[NC]` flag in your rules

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a
>   case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters
>   appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: This won't work by itself, since `$1` will be replaced by different tokens for different requests.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take care of *two* aspects: first the case insensitive matching and second the case conversion to lowercase.

Apache's rewriting module provides the `NC` flag for the first aspect and a somewhat more complex approach to the second one:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash (/) if no such folder exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /${lc:$1}  [NC,L,R=301]

# internally rewrite to a php script if it exists and convert to lower case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /${lc:$1}.php [NC,L]

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ ${lc:$1}  [NC,L,R=301]
```

I have the impression though that your original set of rewriting rules does not really achieve what you attempt to, that is it syntactically invalid even. That is why I changed a few aspects.

Comment: This doesn't work. You may suggest another way of achieving this

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada Would you care to elaborate _what_ will not work and _why_? Or do you simply "suppose"?

Comment: I checked. Even in lower-case gives Internal Error

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada And _what_ error does it throw? An _Internal Error_ has nothing to do with lower or upper case. Please take a look into your http servers error log file and tell us the exact error message.

Comment: In log file: htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: You _did_ realize that I made a few modifications to the first version where I simply copied your (invalid) rule set? Please try again with the current version.

Comment: My rules work :) They remove extension as I need. Your changes throw an error 'Invalid flag delimiters'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125365/discussion-between-arkascha-and-tarlan-mammadzada).